# Type script export module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am working with angular, typescript and gulp, my module system is common js and i try to import a module to my main.ts file and its throw the error:

**Cannot find external module 'modules.ts'.**

main.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import modules from 'modules.ts';

const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

modules.ts:

```
module test {
    export class a {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with just `import modules from 'modules'` ?

Comment: Yes still same error.

Comment: How is your folders structured? Are you sure that are on the same level?

Comment: `import modules from './modules'` ?

Comment: Yes the modules.ts and main.ts are in the same level.

Comment: `import modules = require('modules')`

Comment: No, i try this too before.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that `modules.ts` does not export anything, and therefore will not compile to a valid commonjs module.

Try this:

```
// modules.ts
export module test {

    export class a {

    }
}
```

Then in some other file:

```
import {test} from 'modules';

var foo = new test.a();
```

This should work, read more about the [ES6 Modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242) to learn the ins and outs of the new import/export syntax.

Comment: +1 generally, but to be clear, `modules.ts` is a valid module in the OP's code, but it's not an *external* module, which it needs to be before it can be imported.

Comment: Ok yeah, it will not compile to a valid commonjs module, updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: You've described it in your update as a "commons" module, and in your comment as a "commonjs" module. Neither of these is accurate in TypeScript, which calls these "external" modules, and can compile them to `commonjs` or `amd`. (In the next version it looks like it will also support `system` and `umd`.)

Comment: I misspelled commonjs in the answer, thanks for pointing this out. I know about the different module compile targets in typescript. But the question is asked about commonjs explicitly. That makes referring to a none valid commonjs module correct. I could discuss the different module loading targets at length but this is not the place for that discussion.